# What's the difference between un agriculteur and un fermier?

Tags: choix-de-mot, professions

I'm having difficulty understanding why both agriculteur and fermier are used in this sentence, two words which seem to mean the same thing: farmer.

> À une époque où beaucoup de petits agriculteurs ou fermiers français quittent leur terre pour aller travailler dans des commerces ou des bureaux, moi, j'ai l'intention de lancer une ferme biologique pour cultiver des légumes, des salades et des baies.
>
> At a time when many small French farmers are leaving their land in order to go work in shops or offices, I have the intention of launching an organic farm for cultivating vegetables, salads and berries.

I translated the phrase beaucoup de petits fermiers ou agriculteurs as "many small farmers", but I would appreciate if someone could tell me why both fermiers and agriculteurs are used, as it seems pleonastic.

Comment: Suspicion: worker vs. owner (but with overlap). Consultation of L'internaute corroborates. But on the road now... Confirmation later (or from someone else)!

Comment: Hmmm... @Luke : you're right if we were in 18th century :) but imo nowadays this distinction is no more understood this way. *agriculteur* refers to people who live from *agriculture*. *fermier* refers to people who may live from that but not necessary. Note that *fermier* may be used as an adj. like in *produits fermiers* = *qui viennent de la ferme* which gives a kind of authenticity flavor to a product. Note also that *petits agriculteurs* is closer to *fermier* than *gros agriculteurs* which refers to industrial treatment of the land.

Answer (score 3):

En toute rigueur un fermier est l'exploitant d'une terre louée sous le régime juridique du [fermage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermage).

Agriculteur est un terme plus générique.

Dans l'usage courant, la distinction est plus floue.

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais qu'un agriculteur cultive La terre alors qu'un fermier pratique aussi l'élevage, souvent associé à l'agriculture que ce soit dans un but de diversification ou pour l'alimentation de ses propres bêtes. Peut-être est-ce simplement ma vision de la chose.

"Fermier" me semble également dans l'usage courant plus générique, pouvant servir à qualifier un cultivateur, un éleveur, un employé de ferme,...
Il est aussi parfois utilisé à des fins plus péjoratives, certains préférant donc un terme plus précis car jugé plus "noble".

Answer (score 0):

Agriculteur: owns the land.
Fermier: is renting the land from someone else.
But this difference is not known by people in general.

Answer (score 0):

"Un agriculteur" is more general. It's usually used as a crop-grower and not a person that raises animals.

"un fermier" is a person renting land. A farmer can also raise animals AND grow crops.

Comment: Hi and welcome to French Language SE. I wonder if you could add a source for the claim that a *fermier* is "a person renting land". Does that still apply today or is it obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

La différence est extrêmement floue.

Je pense qu'il faut prendre en compte le temps, il y a fort longtemps il n'y avait que des fermiers, ils avaient des petites fermes, des petites parcelles de terres et quelques animaux, aujourd'hui on parle davantage d'agriculteurs car ce sont des patrons de petites entreprises, avec des revenus importants mais de lourds investissements, de grandes fermes, etc. et on pourrait également les appeler Responsables d'exploitation agricole.

Une évolution du modèle agricole français que certains appelleront les Usines à la campagne.

Je corrige d'autres réponses que j'ai lues : fermier ou agriculteur sont propriétaires de leur ferme. Éventuellement ils peuvent avoir en plus des salariés agricoles, ou être associés (régime GAEC, SARL, SCEA, CUMA), mais ils sont toujours propriétaires de leur ferme et de leurs terres.